# Fight for, fight with, fight against,

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

If I 'fight with B', does it mean that I'm against B? Or B is on my side? If it means the former, what phrase could I use to say that B is on my side when fighting?

Also, does 'fight for' more closely mean to 'fighting to protect something' instead of 'fight alongside something'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Fight alongside' means that you are fighting with B on your side.

'Fight with' means that B is against you.

Yes, 'Fight for' perfectly expresses the feeling of fighting to protect something.